# Modifying SQL query to Data bricks SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, databricks-sql

Rewriting Oracle SQL query to Data bricks SQL query.
Can anyone please help me on below Oracle SQL query that is compatible in Data bricks.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  STT_O_ID AS ANLY_S_ID,
  OG AS OG_ID 
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT 
    M.STT_O_ID,
    M.DEP_U_ID,
    O.OB_OF_ANA_C_ID AS OG 
  FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
      CONNECT_BY_ROOT DEP1.DEP_O_ID STT_O_ID,
      CONNECT_BY_ROOT DEP1.DEP_O_TYP STA_O_TYP,
      DEP1.DEP_U_ID,
      DEP1.DEP_UP_TYP,
      LEVEL L2CHILD,
      (
        SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (DEP1.DEP_U_ID, '/')
      ) PRNT2CHILD_PATH 
    FROM
      (SELECT 
        * 
      FROM
        PR.DEPDGDGCY DEP 
      WHERE DEP.DEP_UP_TYP <> 'ALYC_S' 
        AND DEP.E_DT > SYSDATE) DEP1 CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR DEP1.DEP_U_ID = DEP1.DEP_O_ID 
      AND PRIOR DEP1.DEP_UP_TYP = DEP1.DEP_O_TYP START WITH DEP1.DEP_O_TYP = 'ALYC_S') M 
    LEFT JOIN PR.PLE_NUE_SRC R 
      ON R.PLE_ID = M.DEP_U_ID 
      AND R.E_DT > SYSDATE
    LEFT JOIN PR.REV_SRC_IO RV 
      ON RV.REV_S_ID = R.REV_S_ID 
      AND RV.E_DT > SYSDATE
    LEFT JOIN PR.REV_GOR O 
      ON RV.REV_OIGR_ID = O.REV_OIGR_ID 
  ORDER BY STT_O_ID,
    OG ASC) Y
  LEFT JOIN CRE.O_NMS ORGN 
    ON Y.OG = ORGN.OG_ID 
    AND ORGN.CU_N_IND = 'Y' 
  LEFT JOIN CRE.ORGAFDHTIO OG 
    ON Y.OG = OG.OG_ID 
  LEFT JOIN PR.SM_KY SK 
    ON y.STT_O_ID = SK.SM_KY_O_ID 
    AND SK.SMART_KEY_OBJ_TYP = 'ALYC_S' 
    AND SK.E_DT > SYSDATE
ORDER BY ANLY_S_ID ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
  STT_O_ID AS ANLY_S_ID,
  OG AS OG_ID
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT
    M.STT_O_ID,
    M.DEP_U_ID,
    O.OB_OF_ANA_C_ID AS OG
  FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
      DEP1.DEP_O_ID AS STT_O_ID,
      DEP1.DEP_O_TYP AS STA_O_TYP,
      DEP1.DEP_U_ID,
      DEP1.DEP_UP_TYP,
      LEVEL AS L2CHILD,
      CONCAT_WS('/', SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(DEP1.DEP_U_ID, '/')) AS PRNT2CHILD_PATH
    FROM
      (SELECT *
      FROM PR.DEPDGDGCY DEP
      WHERE DEP.DEP_UP_TYP <> 'ALYC_S'
        AND DEP.E_DT > current_date()) DEP1
    CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR DEP1.DEP_U_ID = DEP1.DEP_O_ID
      AND PRIOR DEP1.DEP_UP_TYP = DEP1.DEP_O_TYP
    START WITH DEP1.DEP_O_TYP = 'ALYC_S') M
    LEFT JOIN PR.PLE_NUE_SRC R
      ON R.PLE_ID = M.DEP_U_ID
      AND R.E_DT > current_date()
    LEFT JOIN PR.REV_SRC_IO RV
      ON RV.REV_S_ID = R.REV_S_ID
      AND RV.E_DT > current_date()
    LEFT JOIN PR.REV_GOR O
      ON RV.REV_OIGR_ID = O.REV_OIGR_ID
  ORDER BY STT_O_ID,
    OG ASC) Y
  LEFT JOIN CRE.O_NMS ORGN
    ON Y.OG = ORGN.OG_ID
    AND ORGN.CU_N_IND = 'Y'
  LEFT JOIN CRE.ORGAFDHTIO OG
    ON Y.OG = OG.OG_ID
  LEFT JOIN PR.SM_KY SK
    ON Y.STT_O_ID = SK.SM_KY_O_ID
    AND SK.SMART_KEY_OBJ_TYP = 'ALYC_S'
    AND SK.E_DT > current_date()
ORDER BY ANLY_S_ID;
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply. But still above query is not compatible with Data bricks. CONNECT BY, START WITH AND SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH is not compatible with Data bricks in your SQL. Can you please help converting into Data bricks. Thank You.